# How to use single APP_id for multiple Bundles ( Multiple apps) pushNotification

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have 3 app. All having the push notification features. According this documentations http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 **only one APPID can use only one Bundle name and both should be same name** so I will be able to get push notification. But I want to use only one APPID for multiple bundle so i will not need to create another APPID.

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any sense.
It's not possible

Comment: Thanks your info. so I needs to create separate **APPID** and also separate certificates?

Comment: separate APPID - yes, separate PUSH certificates - yes, distribution certificate for code signing can be single